# Upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04 fails and APT doesn't work properly

Tags: 12.10, 13.04, upgrade, apt

When trying to upgrade my release from 12.10 to 13.04 I get this output in terminal:

```
axept@aXept-Lifebook:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Ser etter ny utgave av Ubuntu
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 144, in <module>
    fetcher = get_fetcher(options.frontend, m.new_dist, options.data_dir)
  File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 37, in get_fetcher
    from DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeFetcherCore import DistUpgradeFetcherCore
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeFetcherCore.py",       line  30, in <module>
   import tempfile
EOFError: EOF read where not expected
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 64, in              apport_excepthook
from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from apport.report import Report
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os
EOFError: EOF read where not expected

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 144, in <module>
 fetcher = get_fetcher(options.frontend, m.new_dist, options.data_dir)
 File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 37, in get_fetcher
 from DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeFetcherCore import DistUpgradeFetcherCore
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeFetcherCore.py", line      30, in <module>
 import tempfile
EOFError: EOF read where not expected
axept@aXept-Lifebook:~$
```

And when running apt-cache info:

```
axept@aXept-Lifebook:~$ apt-cache policy ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:
Installert: 1:0.190.7
Kandidat:   1:0.190.7
Versjonstabell:
*** 1:0.190.7 0
    500 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 1:0.190.1 0
    500 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
```

And:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Don't do anything. All is up to date apparently..

Trying to launch "Update Manager" gives the same error as "do-release-upgrade".
Tried to remove .pyc files in /etc/apt/dist-packages/ and reinstalled python stuff as found in a Bug-report...

Any suggestion?

This install is NOT new, my laptop has been running fine for months without problems.

Btw, running "Software packages" from "system-settings" doesn't work. It won't start. Suppose its the same reason.. Its been slow to start before, but now it just won't start.

UPDATE: Get the same error when trying to add a repository from terminal.. Whats going on??????

UPDATE 2: When "Update Manager" launch automatic with new system updates, it doesn't work. Nothing happens when I click "Install now" button..

Comment: btw, that "gb" lines in sources.list was just to test another one.. Was the same before they was added..

Comment: It appears that you have a bad python version installed, did you recently install a new version of python?

Comment: Not that I know.. Must be a update then? Have not installed anything new lately.. How to remove and reinstall python?

Comment: The core of it seems to be a corrupt .pyc file. Can you do `apt-get dist-upgrade`. dist-upgrade should work fine, and might replace the croupted files in the process.

Comment: Seems to work..Its installing somethings now, for a change :P I'll get back to you :) -- I know, its installing some kernels..

Comment: Still the same issues.. :(

Comment: Then lets try `apt-get purge python3-distupgrade` and then `apt-get install python3-distupgrade`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9590/discussion-between-coteyr-and-axept)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a running problem anymore.

Re-installed a fresh install of 13.04. Didn't find any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone landing here without the option to reinstall a fresh system, this is what helped me:

I got the same problem after upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10. The upgrade introduces python 3.2 as the default python interpreter.

As discussed [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/1058884) the problem is corrupted `.pyc` files. Reinstalling `python3-distupgrade` as suggested did not have any effect for me.

**Tl;dr**: I ended up needing to reinstall `python3` and `python3-minimal` followed by manually removing all `__pycache__` folders in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3 python3-minimal
sudo find /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages -name '__pycache__' -type d -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

**Caution**: The second command is potentially dangerous if mistyped.

Comment: Ahh, too late for me :( Mine install of 12.10 was not a upgrade from 12.04 and for some reason it was python2.7 that was being used by the system. There was installed python3.2 as well. I tried to change, didn't work. Too bad I didn't try your solution..